# Need some help in querying in MongoDB multiple collections (sorting, searching)

Tags: javascript, mongodb

Hi guys I need some help. I'm getting data from multiple collections patients, referrals, profiles. I'm getting the exactly same data as I want. But now the problem is I have 2 questions.

1. how can I search in these 3 collections by only selected columns like I want to search in some columns in patients and others in referrals and profiles?
2. How can I sort the search result by profiles or any other collection column?

   ```
   let data = Promise.await(Patients.rawCollection().aggregate([
                      {
                        $match: {
                          doctorEmail: email
                        }
                      },
                      {
                        $lookup: {
                          from: "referrals",
                          let: { email: "$email", status: "Return" },
                          pipeline: [
                            {
                              $match:
                              {
                                $expr:
                                {
                                  $and:
                                    [
                                      { $eq: ["$patientEmail", "$$email"] },
                                      { $ne: ["$referralStatus", "$$status"] }
                                    ]
                                }
                              }
                            }
                          ],
                          as: "referrals"
                        },
                      },
                      {
                        $lookup: {
                          from: "profiles",
                          localField: "email",
                          foreignField: "email",
                          as: "profiles",
                        }
                      }
                    ])
   ```

**Here's the collections scehema:**

**patient** (_id, firstName, lastName, patientID, Clinic, eyecondition, phoneNumber, doctorEmail)

**referrals** (_id, doctorEmail, createdAt, firstName, lastName, patientPhoneNumber, patientEmail, message, referralStatus)

**profiles** (_id, fullName, email, phone, address, gender, disease, purpose, subscriptionFlag, fullyActive, subscriptionPaid, ceratedAt, devices, updatedAt, demo)

<--------------------------->

**I would like to search in the following fields:**

**patient** (firstName, lastName, phoneNumber)

**referrals** (referralStatus)

**profiles** (address, gender)

Comment: can you add some sample data of all collections and and that selected fields to search in your question.

Comment: Hi @turivishal, I have added the collection schema below the code and also added the fields in different collections where I need to perform the search.